# How do I look for non-matching values across 3 SQL tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to do what I believe is a double-nested check across three tables, but have no idea how to do so.

I have Table1, Table2, and Table3.
All are tied by an ID and a "Longform" and "Shortform" in Table1:

[image: tables]

**I'm trying to find:**
Entries whose IDs appear in Table2 that *have* the same Longform as those in Table3, but *don't* share the same Shortform.

This is about as far as I've gotten:

```
SELECT T2.Longform,T2.Shortform FROM(
    SELECT Table1.Longform,Table1.Shortform,Table1.ID FROM OuterTable1.Table1
    LEFT JOIN OuterTable2.Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.ID)
    WHERE Table2.ID IS NOT NULL) T2
;
```

I know I'm probably going to have to do another nested select, or a join, on Outertable3.Table3 but I'm not sure which... Or where...

Any help appreciated as always.

Comment: Count `(` and `)`. Same number?

Comment: Table2 has about ~100x less entries than Table3.

Comment: questions like these, you might want to give us some SQL to build some small test tables, plus expected output

Answer (score 2):

Try the  following:

```
Select *
(
    Select T1.*
    from T2
    inner join T1
    on  T1.ID = T2.ID
) as Tab
inner join
(
    Select T1.*
    from T3
    inner join T1
    on T1.ID =  T3.ID
) as Tab2
on Tab.id = Tab2.id
and Tab.Longform = Tab2.Longform
and Tab.Shortform <> Tab2.Shortform
```

Comment: Will have to use null checks if `Shortform` can have null values and the OP wants to consider them.

Answer (score 1):

To get the `longform` join `table1` to `table2` or `table3`. Then use `EXISTS` to check in a subquery if the IDs of `table1` are different but the `longform` is equal.

```
SELECT *
       FROM table2 t21
            INNER JOIN table1 t11
                       ON t11.id = t21.id
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM table3 t32
                                 INNER JOIN table1 t12
                                            ON t12.id = t32.id
                            WHERE t12.id <> t11.id
                                  AND t12.longform = t11.longform);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ID is unique in all three tables

```
Select t2.id,t2.shortform, t1.shortform AS shortformTab1, t2.longform 
                 FROM table2 t2 
                 JOIN table3 t3
                      ON t2.id = t3.id AND t2.longform = t3.longform
                 JOIN table1 t1
                      ON t2.id = t1.id AND t2.shortform != t1.shortform
```